# How to design a custom videoOutput?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The videoOutput I mean is

```
Rectangle {
        width: 320
        height: 240

        Camera{
            id: camera
        }

        VideoOutput {
            id: videoOutput

            anchors.fill: parent
            source: camera
        }    

        GammaAdjust {
            id: gammaAdjust

            anchors.fill: videoOutput
            source: videoOutput
            gamma: 0.5
        }
    }
```

How could I design the videoOutput by myself?
Maybe this is the fastest and easiest way to save the
image after postprocessing,thanks

Edit 1:
The purpose of mine is design a videoOutput which could save the frame after postprocessing.If there are any solution to get the frame buffer of videoOutput, I don't have to design a custom videoOutput.

Comment: What do you mean by "design" in this context? What's your goal?

Comment: The purpose of mine is design a videoOutput which could save the frame after postprocessing

Comment: You mean getting the video after the effects (GammaAdjust) are applied?

Comment: @Frand Osterfeld: yes, you got it, grab is not a solution since it is too slow

Answer (score 1):

[This code](https://gitorious.org/peregrine/peregrine/source/b1491f17e2c98c16104a4a3f7e75e42edf4c1b4b%3aqml-plugin/videooutput/qmlvideo.cpp) may help you, it's a C++ plugin for QML. Cooperating with other QML types may be a hard work, but reading camera and processing image in C++ is always quite easy.